# Calculation of Gradient Penalty for WGAN-GP fails on tensorflow-gpu 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

**EDIT: Added a workaround at the end of the question, although there might still be a bug!**

I have implemented a WGAN-GP (see [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00028), original implementation [here](https://github.com/igul222/improved_wgan_training)) to use it for a translation task of sequence to sequence in a model implemented with Tensorflow 2.0. This includes a gradient penalty to penalize the norm of the gradient of the critic with respect to its input. So far so good ..

My model runs perfectly using tensorflow 2.0 on the CPU of my laptop. When I run the same code on my PC with tensorflow-gpu 2.0 on a RTX2080Ti, I the following error:

```
LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: CudnnRNNBackprop
```

The critic of my WGAN-GP contains GRU-layers, when I switch to a Flatten-layer followed by  Dense-layers, the error does not occur. 
Below you can find a minimum working example to reproduce the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as k
import tensorflow.keras.layers as kl
from tensorflow import random
import numpy as np

D_MODE = "GRU"  # no error on CPU, error on GPU
# D_MODE = "DENSE"  # no error on CPU, no error on GPU
SHAPE = (50, 20)
BATCHSIZE = 32


def gradient_penalty(D, real, fake):
    # get interpolated samples
    alpha = random.uniform([BATCHSIZE, 1, 1], 0., 1.)
    diff = fake - real
    interpolation = real + (alpha * diff)
    # get gradient
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        t.watch(interpolation)
        pred = D(interpolation)
    grad = t.gradient(pred, [interpolation])[0]
    # define gradient penalty
    slopes = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(grad), axis=[1, 2]))
    gp = tf.reduce_mean((slopes - 1.) ** 2)
    return gp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Discriminator / Critic
    discriminator = None
    if D_MODE == "GRU":
        discriminator = k.Sequential(
            [kl.InputLayer(input_shape=SHAPE), kl.GRU(100), kl.Dense(1)]
        )
    elif D_MODE == "DENSE":
        discriminator = k.Sequential(
            [kl.InputLayer(input_shape=SHAPE), kl.Flatten(), kl.Dense(100), kl.Dense(1)]
        )

    # Optimizer
    opt = tf.optimizers.Adam()

    # Dummy data
    real_data = np.random.normal(0, 1, (BATCHSIZE,) + SHAPE).astype(np.float32)
    fake_data = np.random.normal(0, 1, (BATCHSIZE,) + SHAPE).astype(np.float32)

    # Optimize
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        gp = gradient_penalty(D=discriminator, real=real_data, fake=fake_data)

    grad = tape.gradient(gp, discriminator.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, discriminator.trainable_variables))
```

Running this on the desktop PC's CPU, there is no problem. Using an environment with tensorflow-gpu produces the following full output:

```
/home/hendrik/.conda/envs/MLSandbox_TF2GPU/bin/python /home/hendrik/PycharmProjects/GAN/MinimumMinimumWorkingExample.py
2020-02-21 11:50:24.632136: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-02-21 11:50:24.654401: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 11:50:24.654670: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.545
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.655536: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.668918: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.675906: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.678116: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.692943: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.703170: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.730517: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-02-21 11:50:24.730606: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 11:50:24.730917: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 11:50:24.731171: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.731484: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2020-02-21 11:50:24.757387: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3600000000 Hz
2020-02-21 11:50:24.757614: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55f5331c8170 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2020-02-21 11:50:24.757800: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-02-21 11:50:24.758543: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 11:50:24.758856: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.545
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.758879: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.758887: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.758894: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.758902: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.758909: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.758916: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.758924: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-02-21 11:50:24.758958: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 11:50:24.759269: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 11:50:24.759555: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.759775: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-02-21 11:50:24.831796: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-02-21 11:50:24.831809: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0 
2020-02-21 11:50:24.831813: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N 
2020-02-21 11:50:24.831906: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 11:50:24.832200: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 11:50:24.832460: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 11:50:24.832705: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10001 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-02-21 11:50:24.834040: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55f53447e950 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2020-02-21 11:50:24.834048: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, Compute Capability 7.5
2020-02-21 11:50:25.882547: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-02-21 11:50:26.725244: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hendrik/PycharmProjects/GAN/MinimumMinimumWorkingExample.py", line 51, in <module>
    grad = tape.gradient(gp, discriminator.trainable_variables)
  File "/home/hendrik/.conda/envs/MLSandbox_TF2GPU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/backprop.py", line 1014, in gradient
    unconnected_gradients=unconnected_gradients)
  File "/home/hendrik/.conda/envs/MLSandbox_TF2GPU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/imperative_grad.py", line 76, in imperative_grad
    compat.as_str(unconnected_gradients.value))
  File "/home/hendrik/.conda/envs/MLSandbox_TF2GPU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/backprop.py", line 134, in _gradient_function
    grad_fn = ops._gradient_registry.lookup(op_name)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/hendrik/.conda/envs/MLSandbox_TF2GPU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/registry.py", line 97, in lookup
    "%s registry has no entry for: %s" % (self._name, name))
LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: CudnnRNNBackprop
```

I tried to install TF2.1 via pip in my conda environment (although I don't really like using pip in conda, but conda does not have 2.1 yet), but the error remains the same. 
Here is some more background information:

```
(NVIDIA DRIVER) nvidia-smi:
    Nvidia Driver Version: 440.59       
    CUDA Version: 10.2 
(CUDA) nvcc --version: 
    Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.168
(CUDNN) cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2:
    #define CUDNN_MAJOR 7
    #define CUDNN_MINOR 6
    #define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 2

(ANACONDA) conda --version:
    conda 4.6.14
(ANACONDA) related packages from conda list:
    python                    3.6.7             h357f687_1005    conda-forge
    tensorboard               2.0.0              pyhb38c66f_1  
    tensorflow                2.0.0           gpu_py36h6b29c10_0    anaconda
    tensorflow-base           2.0.0           gpu_py36h0ec5d1f_0    anaconda
    tensorflow-estimator      2.0.0              pyh2649769_0    anaconda
    tensorflow-gpu            2.0.0                h0d30ee6_0    anaconda
```

I really hope that someone faced the same problem and found a solution with the problem not being a problem of Cudnn as the error message tells me. 
Thanks in advance for your time dealing with this!

**EDIT:**

The error can not be solved, but avoided by unrolling the recurrent layers. Changing

```
kl.GRU(100)
```

to

```
kl.GRU(100, unroll=True)
```

works without errors. Nevertheless I would suggest to leave the topic open, as I am very interested if this a bug (which I would report as an issue in the TF repo) or not. Furthermore an unrolled RNN layer takes much more memory, which might cause problems for people that use higher sequence lengths (not in my case, but just ignoring the error is the wrong way in my opinion).

Comment: According to the [GRU](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU) documentation, the faster cudnn implementation will be used if the default arguments for GRU are kept. Setting `unroll=False` must use the non-cudnn implementation, which is slower.

Comment: But that makes no sense, since it doesn't even work with `unroll=False` which is the default.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I meant setting `unroll=True` will use the non-cudnn implementation. `unroll=False` is the default for `tf.keras.layers.GRU`. This error is specifically with the cudnn implementation.

Comment: You are right, I didn't take a look at the docs for the GRU before. Thank you! But although it is faster than my laptop this means I am not using the potential of my GPU. So you think it is a bug and raising an issue makes sense?